# Swift - merge files

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems, filemerge

How can I merge files in Swift / iOS ? The `FileManager` can move and copy items but I've seen nothing about merging files. I'd like to have something like

`FileManager.default.merge(files: [URL], to location: URL) throws`

Files can potentially be big, so I'd rather avoid having to pass their data in memory.

=== here is my own in memory merge:

```
let data = NSMutableData()
files.forEach({ partLocation in
  guard let partData = NSData(contentsOf: partLocation) else { return }
  data.append(partData as Data)
  do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: partLocation)
  } catch {
    print("error \(error)")
  }
})
data.write(to: destination, atomically: true)
```

Comment: There's always the option of cooking your own. Read from each file in succession while writing to the destination.

Comment: But is there a thing like "appending to the destination"? If possible I'd like to avoid reading the entire file and then writing to limit memory usage

Comment: That's why you have `FileHandle.readData(ofLength: Int)`. You can make a loop that reads something like 4kb chunks, and writes them to the output. Making the buffer larger would increase  performance by minimizing kernel context switching overhead, but would use more memory

Comment: Thanks. And what can I use to append a chunk of data to an already written file?

Comment: `FileHandle.write(Data)` :)

Comment: get two file’s data，and apend them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own solution (thanks @Alexander for the guidance)

```
extension FileManager {
  func merge(files: [URL], to destination: URL, chunkSize: Int = 1000000) throws {
    try FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: destination.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    let writer = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: destination)
    try files.forEach({ partLocation in
      let reader = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: partLocation)
      var data = reader.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
      while data.count > 0 {
        writer.write(data)
        data = reader.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
      }
      reader.closeFile()
    })
    writer.closeFile()
  }
}
```

Comment: merging is working fine , any idea how to handle memory issue while merging large file ?

Comment: chunkSize controls how much memory is used

Comment: and how can we clear it , when we are merging large file .?.

Comment: What do you mean clear it? I think data reads in memory a part of the size of chunkSize, write it to disk, and then get freed

Comment: yes , while reading from file and writing memory consumption was going very high . I used to inputstream/outputstream to overcome that issue

Answer (score 2):

```
func merge(files: [URL], to destination: URL, chunkSize: Int = 100000000)  {
        for partLocation in files {
            // create a stream that reads the data above
            let stream: InputStream
            stream = InputStream.init(url: partLocation)!
            // begin reading
            stream.open()
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: chunkSize)
            //            var writeData : Data = Data()
            while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
                let read = stream.read(buffer, maxLength: chunkSize)  

                var writeData:Data = Data()
                writeData.append(buffer, count: read)    enter code here
                if let outputStream = OutputStream(url: destination, append: true) {
                    outputStream.open()
                    writeData.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: writeData.count) }
                    outputStream.close()
                    writeData.removeAll()
                }
            }
            stream.close()
            buffer.deallocate(capacity: chunkSize)

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious why you chose to use `writeData.withUnsafeBytes` here instead of simply `outputStream.write(buffer, maxLength: writeData.count)`? It seems like the extra write to Data() isn't required?