# Read text from all rtf files in directory and create master file swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

**Context**
I have an app where the user can write multiple 'scenes'. These are saved as separate file. I need to offer the user 2 options for exporting (to export all scenes individually or all together in one master file).

**What am I try to do** My approach at the moment is to try retrieve the URLs of each file with the extension of .rtf. Then to loop through each, extracting the NSAttributedString. Finally I plan on writing each in turn to a master .rtf file.

**What have I tried** Using ideas from various other answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656808/swift-merge-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327067/append-text-or-data-to-text-file-in-swift) on similar issues I am trying the below which I've annotated to make clear. Needless to say I am a bit stuck and lost for what to do next :

```
@IBAction func exportPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        //THIS BIT RETRIEVES THE URLS OF EACH .RTF FILE AND PUTS THEM INTO AN ARRAY CALLED SCENEURLS. THIS BIT WORKS FINE AND I'VE TESTED BY PRINTING OUT A LIST OF THE URLS.

        do {
            let documentsURL = getDocumentDirectory()
            let docs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options:  [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])
            let scenesURLs = docs.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "rtf" }

//THIS BIT TRYS TO RETURN THE NSATTRIBUTEDSTRING FOR EACH OF THE SCENE URLS. THIS BIT THROWS UP MULTIPLE ERRORS. I SUPPOSE I WOULD WANT TO ADD THE STRINGS TO A NEW ARRAY [SCENETEXTSTRINGS] SO I COULD THEN LOOP THROUGH THAT AND WRITE THE NEW MASTER FILE WITH TEXT FROM EACH IN THE RIGHT ORDER.

            scenesURLs.forEach {_ in

                return try NSAttributedString()(url: scenesURLs(),
                                                options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
                                                documentAttributes: nil)
            } catch {

                print("failed to populate text view with current scene with error: \(error)")

                return nil
            }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

//THERE NEEDS TO BE SOMETHING HERE THAT THEN WRITES THE STRINGS IN THE NEW STRINGS ARRAY TO A NEW MASTER FILE
    }
```

To start with, I just need some help with how to get the strings in an array - I can try work out writing the new master after that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of `NSAttributedString` from the array of file URLs, you can use `map` instead of `forEach`. You also have several syntax issues that need to be fixed.

Replace your use of `forEach` with:

```
let attributedStrings = scenesURLs.compactMap { (url) -> NSAttributedString? in
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(url: url, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't load \(url): \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

If you don't care about logging the error, this can be simplified to:

```
let attributedStrings = scenesURLs.compactMap {
    return try? NSAttributedString(url: $0, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
}
```

To create one final `NSAttributedString` from the array, you can do:

```
let finalAttributedString = attributedStrings.reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString()) { $0.append($1) }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this - I think this will work but am getting an error re compact map... 'compactMap' is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level. I'll have a look into that one now!

Comment: Hey - I changed this to flatMap and it worked fine - now I need to work out how to separate the strings so they have a couple of lines between them!